# Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1 and Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition logging ignored

Tags: spring-tool-suite, tcserver

I was trying to alter the logging that takes place with Pivotal tc Server Developer edition 3.0 and I found out that the java process that starts the server never reads the logging.properties file in catalina base.

I created a new Pivotal tc Server 3.0 with a new instance called diff-instance and added the bio profile.  When it is finished a logging.properties file has been created in the /diff-instannce/conf folder.  I started the server and stopped it and looked at the settings (F3 or open on the list of servers).  It says:

configuration path:

option selected: Use tc Server installation (takes control of tc Server installation)
server path (catalina.base): /diff-instance

Then I stop the server and modify the logging.properties file and noticed that none of the changes I make to this logging.properties file seems to ever be reflected in the tc Server.

I brought in my swiss army knife the good old sysinternals tools (www.sysinternals.com) and started procmon.  To my great surprise the file logging.properties file in the catalina.base conf folder is never read by the javaw.exe process (only the logging.properties in /jre/lib folder is read).  That explains what I saw.

I have 3 important questions related to this:

1. Why is the logging.properties file never read?
2. Where is the method to customize the Pivotal tc Server developer edition documented?  I looked at the "Getting started with Pivotal tc Server" at http://tcserver.docs.pivotal.io/index.html in the section "tc Runtime Instance Configuration Files" on page 29 and it says this file should be used.  Also the "Pivotal tc Server Administration" has a whole section "Configuring Logging for tc Runtime" on page 50 that keeps on talking about this same file.
3. I know there is a lot of glue stuff between tc Server developer and STS.  The whole thing about defining a new server and the options about kind of server locations to define as show below [image: server locations] 
   are all very cool but where is the documentation for this stuff?

This page describes an older version of the tc server and how to change the logging.  It also refers to the logging.properties file in catalina.base.

https://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.6/admin/manual-logging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this was fixed by the STS group.  See comment from Alex Boyko about the tc Server nightly update site http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/eclipse-integration-tcserver/nightly in JIRA [STS-3998](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3998).  In STS 3.6.3 if you select Help/Install new software and you paste this update site and select it you should be able to install a version of the tc Server integration in STS 3.6.3 that fixes this.  This should be fixed in STS 3.6.4.

Comment: the "    Eclipse Integration Commons 3.6.4.201502172336-CI-B27" is needed?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating a tc server instance from the command line and alter the logging for that instance?

Were you able to get the logging working with previous versions of tc Server such as 2.9.x?

If that worked, but the logging for instance you're created via STS didn't work then I think you've uncovered a bug in Tc Server Eclipse integration code. I suspect that perhaps option for logging.properties file needs to be specified at the tc server instance creation time in the creation command somehow.
Please create a bug report for this issue here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse (project: Spring Tool Suite, component: SERVER)

Comment: I never tried this until now so I do not know if it worked before. I installed STS 3.6.3 that comes with tc server 3.0.2 and if I create the instance using tcruntime-instance when I start it in STS I get the following errors:
    Dec 23, 2014 10:08:25 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
    SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener

Comment: Created [STS-3998](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3998) for this issue

Comment: Created [STS-3999](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3999) related issue.